# How to type check a Redux-like connect() function in flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

So I'm doing a project where I basically wrote my own version of Redux and I'm trying to do some very complex typing, and I'm not sure if Flow has the ability to handle it. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, but if I could get this to work it would be super elegant.

Here's my `connect` function

```
// @flow
// TODO: think about how to make this more efficient, since forceUpdate on every subscribe will get inefficient

import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

import type { Store } from './getStore';

function connectToStore<StateType, MappedProps: Object, PassedProps: Object>(
  store: Store<StateType>, 
  mapStateToProps: (StateType) => MappedProps, 
  OldComponent: (PassedProps & MappedProps) => React$Element<*>
) {
  return class Connected extends PureComponent<PassedProps, { storeState: StateType }> {
    unsubscribe: () => void;

    constructor(props: PassedProps, context: any) {
      super(props, context);
      this.state = {
        storeState: store.getState()
      };
      this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe((state) => this.setState({ storeState: state }));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.unsubscribe();
    }

    render() {
      const mappedProps = mapStateToProps(this.state.storeState);
      return React.createElement(OldComponent, { ...this.props, ...mappedProps });
    }
  };
}

export default connectToStore;
```

So what should happen is that the typing of this component should make it so that if I call this function on component C, then it will evaluate the props of C and check to make sure that the props passed into the component combined with the props from mapStateToProps satisfy every prop requirement of C.

However what happens is basically no type checking at all. I don't have to fill any of the prop requirements of C (neither in the mapToProps function  or in the props that get passed in from the immediate parent) and flow accepts it regardless. Is this beyond flow's capabilities? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score -2):

Pretty much you just want to use a good framework like Angular